# How to set the custom previous and next button for my UIWebView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

i have create a custom `UIWebView` for my project.now i load one website that `UIWebView` and also create two button like previous page and next page on top of navigation bar. i want to know how to handle the UIWebView pages,when i click the previous or next button.Those buttons handle the `UIWebView` pages.i need exact code for the those previous and next buttons.could any one help please. thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question isn't exactly on topic for this site. Please read the help section's post relating to questions you can ask here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to goForward and GoBack.

```
- (IBAction) buttonGoBack
{
    if ([webView canGoBack]) 
    {
        [webView goBack];
    }
}

- (IBAction) buttonGoForward
{
    if ([webView canGoForward]) 
    {
        [webView goForward];
    }
}
```